# Can't see the VLAN-tag in L3 Netfilter hooks

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, netfilter, vlan

Something bad happens with my `skb` while it travels through the Linux network stack. Perhaps I need to check all registered hook to find if the problem is there? How can I do it in runtime or searching through Linux source code?

UPD:
I send particular vlan tagged packets to my system. I dump vlan tags of all inbound skbs in rx_handler and in Netfilter hook.
In rx_handler `skb->vlan_tci` is OK, but in Netfiltr hook `skb->vlan_tci` is zero, so I'm trying to find where it can be spoiled (probably in another hook). Btw my skb is just all ingress skbs.

Comment: What do you mean by *"my skb"*?

Comment: I send paticular vlan tagged packets to my system. I dump vlan tags of all inbound skbs in rx_handler and in netfilter hook, in rx_handler skb->vlan_tci is OK, but in netfiltr hook skb->vlan_tci is zero, so I'm trying to find where it can be spoiled (probably in another hook). So, my skb is just all ingress skbs.

Comment: Probably I need a place in the kernel where all netfilter hooks are called.

Comment: Which exaclty `->rx_handler` is used?

Comment: It is a bit strange that you see `skb->vlan_tci` in rx_handler and don't see it in hooks. It most likely that it would be conversely, because the vlan untagging is done in [`__netif_receive_skb_core()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/core/dev.c#L3911), so `vlan_tci` is likely to be present in hooks.

Comment: Perhaps is hits this some cases where `skb->vlan_tci = 0` is happened. Please add some details. Show how you print it both from rx_handler and hook, and how is it printed eventually

Comment: Well, studying through the code I came to the same conclusion, it seems like  __netif_receive_skb_core() does the stripping of vlan tag from data, and further after rx_handlers calls  skb->vlan_tci = 0 happens and only after that netfilter hooks are called